# No measurements from input from telegraf to influxdb

Tags: linux, devops, influxdb, telegraf

In short that is my problem:
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4399
I see it wasn't answered, but I also have it.

These are logs from access log. Please help me

```
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:13:40 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:13:50 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:00 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:10 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:20 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4596 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:30 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:40 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:14:50 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:15:00 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
192.168.0.122 - - [18/Oct/2018:13:15:10 +0300] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4598 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by changing system rights of telegraf service.
Also telegraf does not notify that it cannot read access logs.